# Need help creating custom filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assume I have two columns of data in my Excel sheet. Column A is name, and column B is email address.

- Lukas, NULL
- Lukas, NULL
- Lukas, NULL
- Bob, bob@hello.com
- Bob, NULL
- Bob, NULL
- Michael, NULL

and so on.

What kind of filter can I apply so I only see

1. people for whom there doesn't exist a duplicate in Column A AND who don't have an email address (i.e. column B is NULL) and,
2. people who have duplicates in column A but none of which have an email address? Basically, if my sheet only had the data above, I'd like the filtered sheet to display:

   - Lukas, NULL
   - Lukas, NULL
   - Lukas, NULL
   - Michael, NULL

Thanks in advance!

Lukas

Comment: Why would *Lukas* be in your list is part of your criteria is *'people for whom there doesn't exist a duplicate in Column A'*? I get the part about *Bob* but either *Lukas* or *Michael* would be listed according to what you've stated, not both.

Answer (score 0):

I would use COUNTIFS to find how many duplicates there were for each person (in C2):-

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$8,"="&A2)
```

and to find how many with a NULL email address (in D2):-

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$8,"="&A2,B$2:B$8,"=NULL")
```

If both counts are equal to 1, it satisfies your criterion 1.

If both counts are equal but greater than 1, it satisfies your criterion 2.

In fact (I think) they both boil down to one criterion, that all occurrences must have no email address. So in E2:-

```
=C2=D2
```

Then just filter on column E

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an Advanced Filter.

Move your table down to about row 6, and put column headers in A5:B5

In A2, put your criteria formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Name,A6,Email,"*@*")=0
```

[image]

I defined Name to refer to A6:A12, and Email to  B6:B12, but you could use absolute references in their place.

Then, select the Advanced Filter, select your ranges (select A1:A2 for the Criteria, even though A1 might be empty.  And select to either filter in place, or copy to a new location

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]